# Google App Engine uploading file in ordinary form

Tags: python, google-app-engine

There is an form consisting of ordinary HTML form elements and uploading file together. When i use it, file uploading works but ordinary form don't.
Can i set it?
Handling function below:

```
class OSCForm(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/oscform.html')

        template_values = {
            'action_url': upload_url
        }

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('oscform.html')

        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
        osc=OSC()

        osc.f_title=self.request.get('f_title') 
        osc.f_id=self.request.get('f_id') 
        osc.f_os=self.request.get('f_os') 
        osc.f_bnf=self.request.get('f_bnf') 
        osc.f_contractor=self.request.get('f_contractor') 
        osc.f_loc=self.request.get('f_loc') 
        osc.f_adr=self.request.get('f_adr') 
        osc.f_exp1=self.request.get('f_exp1') 
        osc.f_exp2=self.request.get('f_exp2') 
        osc.f_ipa=self.request.get('f_ipa') 
        osc.f_type=self.request.get('f_type') 
        osc.f_date=self.request.get('f_date') 
        osc.f_level=self.request.get('f_level')

        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        blob_key=upload.key()

        osc.f_annex=blob_key

        savedosc=osc.put()
```

By the way; HTML form is below

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="CONTROLRECORDS" id="CONTROLRECORDS" action="{{action_url}}">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_title">Contract Title</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="f_title" class="required" name="f_title" style="background-image: url(http://www.reformedapp.com/themes/reformed-form-start/images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png); background-position: 50% 100%; background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;" />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_id">Contract ID</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="f_id" class="required" name="f_id" />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_os">Operation Structure</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="f_os" id="f_os">
                <option value="MoEU">MoEU</option>
                <option value="MoLSS">MoLSS</option>
                <option value="MoSIT">MoSIT</option>
                <option value="MoTMC">MoTMC</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_bnf">Beneficiary</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="f_bnf" name="f_bnf" />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_contractor">Contractor</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="f_contractor" name="f_contractor" />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_loc">Related Location of Project</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="f_loc" id="f_loc">
                <option value="ANKARA">ANKARA</option>
                <option value="ISTANBUL">ISTANBUL</option>
                <option value="ADANA">ADANA</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_adr">Adress(District or Village Name)</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="f_adr" name="f_adr" value="CENTER" />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_exp">Expert 1</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="f_exp" id="f_exp">
                <option value="">SUAT ATAN</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_exp2">Expert 2</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="f_exp2" id="f_exp2">

                <option value="">SUAT ATAN</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_ipa">IPA component</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="f_ipa" id="f_ipa">
                <option value="IPA1">IPA1</option>
                <option value="IPA2">IPA2</option>
                <option value="IPA3">IPA3</option>
                <option value="IPA4">IPA4</option>
                <option value="IPARD">IPARD</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_type">Contract Type</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="f_type" id="f_type">
                <option value="WORKS">WORKS</option>
                <option value="SUPPLY">SUPPLY</option>
                <option value="GRANT">GRANT</option>
                <option value="SERVICE">SERVICE</option>

            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_date">OSC Date</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="f_date" class="date" name="f_date"  />
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_level">Control Level</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select size="1" name="f_level" id="f_level">
                <option value="DESKREVIEW">DESKREVIEW</option>
                <option value="DESKREVIEW+OSC">DESKREVIEW+OSC</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="f_obs">Observations</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <textarea id="f_obs" name="f_obs" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
            <br>
            Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> 

        </dd>       
    </dl>
    <div id="submit_buttons">
        <button type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What's not working as expected?

Comment: Thing is that: for example we have a form include name surname and avatar image field. Handler class is like above. When we test; avatar is uploaded but name and surname entry isn't created on data store . That's all. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML form?